# How to get substring between two numbers (of unknown digit length) in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a string that looks like this `a = 'readyM01JUN_01_18_0144.xlsx'` and I would like to tease out the `JUN`.

I thought first trying to split `a` with respect to digits, but `a.split('[0-9]+')` doesn't work. Any ideas ?

Comment: Depending on what you really want to get, `re.search(r'\d(\D+)\d', s).group(1)` or `re.search(r'\d([^_\d]+)_\d', s).group(1)`. If `a` is a string, `split` in your case only accepts a literal string to split, not a regex. To split with a regex pattern, you need `re.split`.

Comment: @anubhava i edited the title, i hope it is more clear now

Comment: Can you paste, what is input string samples(`a = 'readyM01JUN_01_18_0144.xlsx'` or just `readyM01JUN_01_18_0144.xlsx`) and what output do you want?

Comment: @nandal I want as output `JUN`, and the input is `a = 'readyM01JUN_01_18_0144.xlsx'` as a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `a` is a string, `split` in your case only accepts a literal string to split, not a regex. To split with a regex pattern, you need `re.split`.

However, you may use

```
import re
a = 'readyM01JUN_01_18_0144.xlsx'
m = re.search(r'\d([^_\d]+)_\d', a) # Or, r'\d([a-zA-Z]+)_\d'
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/1ZmGyy)

**Pattern details**

- `\d` - a digit
- `([^_\d]+)` - Group 1 matching and capturing (`m.group(1)` will hold this value) 1+ chars other than digits and `_` (you may even use `([a-zA-Z]+)` to match 1+ ASCII letters)
- `_\d` - a `_` and a digit.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/GH4SYO/1).

Note that `re.search` returns the *first* leftmost match.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your program objective is, but if JUN stands for June, and you have a series of months and your data and want to remove them all, I would create a list of months, iterate through them, and then replace them in the particular string you are working on. You can get JUN out of the string by using the .remove() variable on a and then placing it as the value of a new variable a, since strings are immutable. Here is an example:

```
months = ['JAN', 'FEB', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEPT', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC']
a = 'readyM01JUN_01_18_0144.xlsx'

for month in months:
   if month in a:
      a = a.replace(month, '')
      print(a)
```

OUTPUT:

```
readyM01_01_18_0144.xlsx
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try an iterative approach like this:

```
import re

def remove_string(string, sub):
    res = string
    reduce = 0
    for loc in re.finditer(sub, string):
        res = res[:loc.start()+reduce] + res[loc.start()+len(sub)+reduce:]
        reduce -= len(sub)

    return res
```

Which Outputs:

```
>>> remove_string('readyM01JUN_01_18_0144.xlsx', 'JUN')
readyM01_01_18_0144.xlsx
>>> remove_string('readyM01JUN_01_18_0144JUN.xlsx', 'JUN')
readyM01_01_18_0144.xlsx
```